# Html div border goes outside viewport

Tags: html, css

OK This seems really basic, but I can't seem to find an answer, maybe my search terms have been too general?

I have defined a top-level div that has a border round it, I want this to be the maximum size of the viewport.

This is the code in its most basic form

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
            test
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
#main {
    position:absolute;    
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px green solid;
}
```

See this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GpBS5/11/

The Div should have a 1px green border which is visible, but it always seems to have the bottom and right just off the display needing a scrollbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpBS5/12/)

The width and height of the div is 100% + 2px (2 borders, a pixel each), which requires scrollbars. `box-sizing: border-box` fixes this because it tells the browser to included the padding and border in the width and height.

I almost always use:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a default margin on the body. Add this to reset it to 0:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

PLUS: Add `box-sizing: border-box;`to your `#main` DIV.

http://jsfiddle.net/gqL1zqeo/1/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't solve the problem and the additional margin doesn't affect the border.

Comment: sorry, saved the fiddle in the wrong state... updated now